# Android html.fromhtml() url intents

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-view, textview

Is it possible that the hyperlinks in the parsed html from Html.fromHtml() start a intent. I put this parsed html from Html.fromhtml() in a textview.

I can't find anything on google or the Android developers website.

Comment: use <a href="...">...</a> tag

Comment: I know... but then it only makes the a tag blue colored but when I click it nothing happends.

Comment: what href have you used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use this:

```
import android.text.method.LinkMovementMethod;
import android.text.util.Linkify;



  SpannableString str = new SpannableString("your string");
  Linkify.addLinks(str, Linkify.WEB_URLS);

  textview.setText(str);
  textview.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're asking, but if I squint right, you might be talking about behavior due to [auto-linkifying](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3aautoLink):

> Controls whether links such as urls and email addresses are automatically found and converted to clickable links. The default value is "none", disabling this feature.

Comment: This works, but it only works if a full URL is in the text, Html.fromHtml() parses the A tags with a href to a blue color that looks like it's clickable but it issen't.

Comment: Have a look at [`android:linksClickable`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:linksClickable)?

Comment: I have set linksClickable to true, but no luck :/

Comment: @WesleyEgbertsen Ah, yes, I forgot about that weird behavior. The auto-linking works for plain text.  For HTML, you don't need any of that, just call `setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());` on your TextView.

Comment: Is it also possible to make the text selectable, because textIsSelectable doesen't work anymore with movementmethod.